# как после прочтения текстового файла в webView занести информацию в sqlite андройд

Tags: java, android, база-данных

у меня есть файл `txt` в первичной внешней памяти(не съемной)`андройда`. я вывожу текст в `webView` как мне его положить в базу данных `sqlite`? пишут что то про скрипты но если информация не с сайта берется то как делать не представляю.в базу я могу строки засунуть а как эти строки получить конкретно из `webView` .заранее извиняюсь если вопрос глупый я новичок недавно начала заниматься разработкой.
этапы(с кодом или без не важно) что нужно делать, любая абсолютно информация.

Comment: Не до конца понял, можете положить в SQL, или нет? Для работы с SQL  обычно использую Room. [Вот неплохое пособие](https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/dagger-2/27-course/architecture-components/524-urok-1.html), если хотя бы поверхностно знакомы с реляционными базами. Там с 5го урока по теме, но советую первые то же прочитать, поскольку RX Java это прикольно и полезно

Comment: из веб вю я получить не могу ничего что записала

Comment: было бы проще, если бы вы добавили к вопросу код который вы используете и объяснили смысл применения в нем WebView. Вы загружаете в него html код из файла? Подозреваю, что можно обойтись вообще без WebView